# Are digit separators allowed before the digits in a hex or binary number?

Tags: c++, c++14, digit-separator

C++14 introduced the concept of digit separators into literals, along the lines of `3'141'592'653'589`. Now this is a *great* feature for readable code but I was wondering whether it allowed quotes *before* the numeric portion of a `0x/0b`-type literal. It seems to me that:

```
unsigned int topThreeBits = 0b'1110'0000;
unsigned int hexNum       = 0x'dead'beef;
```

is more readable than the one *without* a leading separator:

```
unsigned int topThreeBits = 0b1110'0000;
unsigned int hexNum       = 0xdead'beef;
```

because it clearly delineates the base from the digits.

Since I don't yet have a C++14 compiler, I need confirmation one way or another as to whether it allows this.

I know it doesn't make sense for un-prefixed numbers like `'123'456`, especially since the parser wouldn't know if it was meant to be a `char` variable or a numeric literal.

But, for prefixed literals, I can't see there's any confusion as to what the token is meant to be at the point the first `'` arrives - the `0x/0b` has already dictated it's going to be a numeric literal.

Comment: I just wondered the same. As the answer says, it can't be done (yet?). So to get symmetrical numbers/nibbles/etc, we have to settle for the next best thing: `0b0'1110'0000` ([hmm](https://sites.google.com/site/ohmusicstudent/_/rsrc/1315398151002/band-instruments/oboe/oboe-history/oboe2.gif)) and `0x0'dead'beef` ([omg](http://londonpride.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Oxo__Beef________4c23b399c6687.jpg))

Comment: @underscore_d, the leading `0` is actually a brilliant idea, not one I'd thought of. The leading zero has no effect on the value and it still allows for a visually distinct "real number portion".

Comment: Yup, simple but effective, and sometimes such things are easy to miss :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If we look at the grammar from the [draft C++14 standard: N4140](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n4140.pdf) section `2.14.2` *[lex.icon]*, it is not allowed right after the base indicator of hexadecimal or binary literals:

```
binary-literal:
  0b binary-digit
  0B binary-digit
  binary-literal ’opt binary-digit
[...]
hexadecimal-literal:
  0x hexadecimal-digit
  0X hexadecimal-digit
  hexadecimal-literal ’opt hexadecimal-digit
```

Although, octal literals do allow the separator after the base indicator:

```
octal-literal:
  0
  octal-literal ’opt octal-digit
```

We can also check using one of the online compiler which provide C++14 compilers such as [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/42736b1305902325) or [Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/bAOmGLMQyO7djn41).

The Evolution Working Group issue which tracked this change was [issue 27: N3781 Single-Quotation-Mark as a Digit Separator, N3661, N3499 Digit Separators, N3448 Painless Digit Separation](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4422.html#27). I don't see an obvious rationale for this design decision, perhaps it is solely a literal interpretation of *digit separator*.

Note we can find a list of the draft standards from [Where do I find the current C or C++ standard documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/81656/1708801).

Comment: Thanks for that. Nice links too, I've been using codingground but that only appears to go to gcc 4.8.x which is not C++14.

Comment: Except for the octal base indicator. It is allowed immediately after the `0`.

Comment: @hvd I should have been more specified, I updated my answer.

Comment: An interesting question is whether the lexical grammar could be extended to allow it.  I have to admit I like the look.  It is especially helpful for octal (though that works).  IIRC when I implemented digit seps in g++ it looked like I could allow it without breaking things.

Comment: @emsr it looks like it could be supported without a problem, I have not thought too deeply about it.  None of the four proposals linked from the EWG issue give a rationale for that decision. I wonder if perhaps it was just thought of a literally as a *digit sperator*.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I remember having to keep the words _digit separator_ in my mind as I was building and testing.  I think that's it.  I remember having to special case the bit right after 0[xXbB].  I wonder if it's worth a little paper.

Comment: @emsr it seems like a reasonable proposal, let me know if ever turns into a proposal.